# Plotting a graph from multiple pandas data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas data frame with many columns (150), 140 out of them (the 10th column through out the 150th column) represent the weather degree values through time (through 140 days). Each column represents the degree for a different day.
For two rows in my data frame (each row represents a different city), I want to plot a trend of all weather points, starting from the first (the 10th column), to the last (the 150th column).

I can't manage to do it with the data frame as it is.
Should I create a pivot table first? a list?

Do you have any idea how to approach it in an efficient way?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the sample data? It will help us to make a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select specified columns from your dataset, you can use [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function. For example, let's create the new dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['a',2,3,4,5],
    ['b',2,3,4,5],
    ['c',2,3,4,5],
    ['d',2,3,4,5],
]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for d in data:
    record = {
        'city': d[0],
        'WAKA1': d[1],
        'WAKA2': d[2],
        '2019-01-01': d[3],
        '2019-01-02': d[4]
    }
    df = df.append(record, ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Then let's filter it with data regex:

`df.filter(regex=('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'))`

[image]

After it, you can visualize filtered data with any viz library.